# Add .net Framework 4.0 automatic web installation to msi file already built

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix3.6

I have a msi file working good. Now I want create a project that instal .net Framework 4.0 from web if needed, and after run my msi.

I try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Test"
    UpgradeCode="5e5f0f1e-58e0-42e5-8306-37533d677535">
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />
      <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="MyMsi.msi" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
light.exe : error LGHT0001 : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

How fix it? Or it's there other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the bootstrapper project references [WixNetfxExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html).